# Calling emacsclient from ansi-term makes emacsclient hang, how do I get around this?

Tags: emacsclient, ansi-term

Sometimes I use `ansi-term` in emacsclient instead of directly using my shell. When I do this, it is not an infrequent occurrence that I forget where I am and call `emacsclient someFile`, which freezes the terminal window and doesn't let me start a new emacsclient process. Is there a way to make invocations of emacsclient in `ansi-term` instead open the file? Or some other way to unfreeze this? The only solution I have found is to `kill` the server process.

Comment: FYI it's not normal for Emacs to freeze in that scenario. I can happily nest Emacs instances inside `term` buffers, without issue. Check with `emacs -Q` (and running `emacs -Q -nw` in the term buffer). If that works, you could then recursively bisect your config to determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: @phils it doesn't freeze when I do that. I think it might be because I am already in a client, and my Emacs is aliased to try to open a new client.

Comment: That's missing information from your question, then. Please update the text with the appropriate details. It sounds like you're "calling emacsclient" rather than "calling emacs". I suggest eliminating aliases from the equation, and just providing the (unaliased) commands to trigger the issue under `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: I made a hacky way around this - the env variable $EMACS is set if you are in emacs, so I changed my alias for my editor to launch emacsclient only if it isn't set, otherwise fail and print error message. Works so far, would still be interested in a more elegant solution though.

Comment: Note: this is [Bug#22639](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22639)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ansi-term` sets the `TERM` environment variable to `eterm`, possibly extended to `eterm-color` or similar. You can use this to define `emacs` to an appropriate alias whenever you're already in `ansi-term` inside emacs. Something like this in your `.bashrc`:

```
case "$TERM" in 
     eterm*)
         alias emacs=emacsclient
         ;;
     *)
         ## code to run for non-eterm shells
         ;;
esac
```

If that doesn't work, another option is the environment variable `INSIDE_EMACS`, which is set to `<emacs version>,term<term version>`. Note that `shell-mode` sets this to `<emacs version>,comint`, so if you use both you'll want to distinguish between them with your test:

```
case "$INSIDE_EMACS" in 
     *term*)
         alias emacs=emacsclient
         ;;
     *comint*)
         ## code to run for shell-mode
         ;;
     *)
         ## code for non-emacs shells
esac
```

Comment: Hmm, when I run `echo $TERM` in `ansi-term` I get `xterm-256color` - this is the same thing I get when run it in a normal shell

Comment: There isn't much documentation for ansi-term, so I'm mostly guessing based on what I see when I run it on my machine. Try running `env` from within ansi-term - maybe you'll see a variable there that is different from your regular xterm shell that you can use instead.

Comment: @Andrew you must have customized `term-term-name` for that to be true (or set `TERM` in your .bashrc?). You could also check `$INSIDE_EMACS`.

Comment: I believe the `INSIDE_EMACS` environment variable is the correct way to test for this. Its value can vary (e.g. it will be different between `M-x shell` and a shell run in `M-x term`), so you would probably just want to test for `[ -n "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]`

Answer (score 0):

See "with-editor" : https://github.com/magit/with-editor/blob/master/README.md

You don't have to display an error when using emacsclient from inside term : you can make it use your current Emacs instance.

For shell-mode, there is a package called "shx", which provides useful shell commands like :e (to edit a file), :diff (to ediff 2 files ), :find (run find command and open files in clickable output) etc.

Edit : and yes, you never need to kill the server process too. On unixes, just send it a USR2 signal and Emacs would drop whatever it was doing and unfreeze from most situations including this one.

" killall -USR2 emacs"